# How to get word under cursor using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I need to get this feature in my application using angularJS, so that each word gets displayed on the move of cursor above it?
The catch is that the paragraph is dynamically generated by ng-bind and I need to see each word with the move hover

```
<p>Each word will be wrapped in a span.</p>
<p ng-bind="myparagraph"></p>
Word: <span id="word"></span>

    $('p').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.html($this.text().replace(/\b(\w+)\b/g, "<span>$1</span>"));
    });
     // bind to each span
    $('p span').hover(
        function() { $('#word').text($(this).css('background-color','#ffff66').text()); },
        function() { $('#word').text(''); $(this).css('background-color',''); }
    );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5gyRx/

Comment: You already have code, just wrap it into directive.

Answer (score 1):

use a directive:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.model = {
    word: "",
    paragraph1: "Each word will be wrapped in a span.",
    paragraph2: "A second paragraph here."
  };
});


app.directive('wordUnderCursor', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      wordUnderCursor: "=",
      wordUnderCursorContent: "="
    },
    link: function(scope, elment) {

      scope.$watch('wordUnderCursorContent', function(newValue) {
        console.log(newValue);
        if (newValue) {
          var $element = $(elment);

          $element.html(newValue.replace(/\b(\w+)\b/g, "<span>$1</span>"));

          $element.find('span').hover(
            function() {
              var $span = $(this);
              $span.css('background-color', '#ffff66');
              scope.$apply(function() {
                scope.wordUnderCursor = $span.text();
              });
            },
            function() {
              var $span = $(this);
              $span.css('background-color', '');
              scope.$apply(function() {
                scope.wordUnderCursor = "";
              });
            }
          );
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

html:

```
   <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
     Paragraph 1:
     <input type="text" ng-model="model.paragraph1"></input> <br />
     Paragraph 2:
     <input type="text" ng-model="model.paragraph2"></input>

    <p word-under-cursor="model.word" word-under-cursor-content="model.paragraph1"></p>
    <p word-under-cursor="model.word" word-under-cursor-content="model.paragraph2"></p>
    Word: {{model.word}}
  </body>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/vRwCdXhtEFm7A4au1ago?p=preview

Comment: The content of my paragraph is dynamic...so how can I make it work for something like :
<p word-under-cursor="model.word" ng-bind="myparagraph"></p>

Comment: @user3595524 i updated my plunker to make it dynamic